# Lambda in VPC cannot connect to AWS services

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, endpoint, amazon-vpc, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have a lambda in a VPC because it needs to access a database. Now this lambda will also have to be able to use Firehose Kinesis Video streams (https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/video-streams/). My lambda is built in Python and this is my code for creating a kinesis video client:

```
client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo')
def create_stream(stream_name):
    response = client.create_stream(
        DeviceName='BE',
        StreamName=stream_name,
        MediaType='video/h264',
        DataRetentionInHours=1,
        Tags={
            'string': 'Livestream'
        }
    )
    stream_ARN = response['StreamARN']
    print('Printing ARN: ', stream_ARN)
    return stream_ARN
```

Now when I call create_stream('TEST'), my lambda times out after 90 seconds:

```
[DEBUG] 2019-11-05T15:02:47.66Z 2e094ebe-8a92-4a10-ab6c-433cf223cb5b retry needed, retryable exception caught: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/createStream"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
(self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
raise err
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/botocore/httpsession.py", line 262, in send
chunked=self._chunked(request.headers),
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 641, in urlopen
_stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 344, in increment
raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
raise value
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 603, in urlopen
chunked=chunked)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 843, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connection.py", line 316, in connect
conn = self._new_conn()
File "/var/runtime/urllib3/connection.py", line 165, in _new_conn
(self.host, self.timeout))
urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<botocore.awsrequest.AWSHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fcf62a7e128>, 'Connection to kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com timed out. (connect timeout=60)')
```

Of what I understand, my lambda fails to connect to https://kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/createStream because its in a VPC. To test this, I created a new temporary lambda outside my VPC and it worked perfectly fine, it could connect to Kinesis Video Stream without problems.

To fix this issue, I understand that I have to create an Endpoint so that my lambda in my VPC can access a AWS service such as Kinesis Video Streaming. I went to the VPC endpoint console and created a new endpoint. I selected the "com.amazonaws.eu-west-1.kinesis-streams" service and made sure to use the same VPC, subnets and Security group as my lambda. Once the endpoint was created, I tried calling create_stream again. Unfortunatly, I get the same result, a timeout when trying to connect.

So my question is: Is it possible at all to a AWS service from an VPC? If so, how?

**UPDATE**

As a response to answers I have now tried the following but I still get the same error:

My Lambda in VPC has a SG with All outbound permission. Then I created a new SG that has inbound from the VPC SG and then assigned it to the endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

When an AWS Lambda function is *not* connected to a VPC, it has full access to the Internet.

When an AWS Lambda function *is* connected to a VPC, it will *not* have direct access to the Internet. To grant such access, you will need either:

- A **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet, with matching Route tables, *or*
- A **VPC Endpoint** in the VPC for the desired service

If using a VPC Endpoint, configure the security groups as follows:

- Create a **security group for the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`)

  - Grant default "All Outbound" permission
  - There is no need for an Inbound rule
- Create a **security group for the VPC Endpoint** (`Endpoint-SG`)

  - Grant **Inbound** access from `Lambda-SG`

That is, the `Endpoint-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG` in the Inbound rules. This will permit the Lambda function to access the VPC Endpoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I just tried exactly this. My Lambda in VPC has a SG with All outbound permission. Then I created a new SG that has inbound from the VPC SG and then assigned it to the endpoint. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible to call other services via a lambda deployed into the vpc.

As mentioned endpoint is needed which you have already configured. In this case the issue seems to be with the outbound ports.

Have you configured the outbound in the security group attached to your lambda ?

Comment: yes, you said you "made sure to use the same VPC, subnets and Security group as my lambda", but being part of the same Security Group does not guarantee connectivity.  You need an inbound rule that will allow the VPC Endpoint to receive traffic from the Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked more closely at your code. It appears that you are using **Amazon Kinesis Video**, which is different to **Amazon Kinesis Data Streams**.

From what I can see, the VPC Endpoint is available for Data streams, but no Video.

That's why it can't reach the `kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint.

If so, then you'll need to launch a **NAT Gateway** in the public subnet, and update Route Tables accordingly. The Lambda function will then be able to reach Kinesis.

Comment: Thanks, how should the route table be configured?  I tried crearting a new NAT Gateway with my Lambda's subnet. I then created new route table that routes 0.0.0.0/0 to my NAT Gateway's id. I also added Subnet Assocications to the lambda Subnet to the route table. I followed the isnturctions here: https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12

Comment: Sounds good! Does it work for you? The main things to check are that the Lambda function is associated with _private_ subnets, the Route Table sends `0.0.0.0/0` to the NAT Gateway, and the NAT Gateway is in a _public_ subnet. You can then test that Lambda has Internet connectivity with a short function like `import urllib.request \ print(urllib.request.urlopen('https://wikipedia.com').read())`.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I had accidently picked the wrong subnet when creating my NAT Gateway!